# onsubmit passes even when js function returns false

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

I've read many posts considering this problem and for some reason none of the solutions work for me. I have several js functions for validation that are called in the main one that is appointed to the onSubmit tag in the form. Here is the js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validacijaForme() {

var username = document.getElementById('usname');
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var pass1 = document.getElementById('pass1');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2');


 if(validacijaUsername(username) && validacijaEmail(email) && validacijaSifri(pass1,pass2))
{
  alert('success');
  return true;
}

return false;
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validacijaSifri(fieldId1, fieldId2)
{
var two = document.getElementById(fieldId1).value;
var three = document.getElementById(fieldId2).value;
if(two == three) { return true; }
alert("Warning!! passcodes must match!!!");
return false;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validacijaUsername(usname)
{
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
if(letters.test(usname.value))  
{  
  return true;  
}  
else  
{  
  alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');  
  document.getElementById('usrname').focus();  
  return false;  
} 
}
</script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
function validacijaEmail(email)
{
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
if(mailformat.test(email))  
{  
  return true;  
}  
else  
{  
  alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");  
  document.getElementById(email).focus(); 
  return false;  
 }  

}
```

and here is the html form code

```
<form class="form-signin" onSubmit="return validacijaForme();" name="registerForm" method = "POST" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Registracija</h2>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="usrname" id="usname" autofocus>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" id="email">
<input  type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass" id="pass1">
<input  type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password" id="pass2">
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="dugme" type="submit">Register</button>
```

The problem is that all the alerts are working, meaning that those functions do validate the fields, and should return false, but the onSubmit tag doesn't seem to accept that value from the function. 
The form doesn't submit and doesn't pass to test.php only if I type this:

```
 <form class="form-signin" onSubmit="return false" name="registerForm"  method = "POST" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Can you give us link?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand, link for what?

Comment: You have many errors in your functions

Answer (score 0):

submit the form with javascript `submit()`

```
<form id="myform" class="form-signin" onSubmit="validacijaForme();" name="registerForm" 
method = "POST" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And in your function:

```
function validacijaForme() {
var username = document.getElementById('usname');
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var pass1 = document.getElementById('pass1');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2');

if(validacijaUsername(username) && validacijaEmail(email) && validacijaSifri(pass1,pass2))
{
alert('success');
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
return false;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: you also put the id in the form tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to your username id/name consistency. Use the console (F12) to debug this kind of thing.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="usRname" id="usname" autofocus>
```

Change:

```
    document.getElementById('usrname').focus();
```

To:

```
    document.getElementById('usname').focus();
```

Comment: thank you so much I haven't noticed that at all, that was a part of the problem, the other part was that I was calling document.getElementById('usname').focus(); and there was no need for that since I have passed the element to the function, it must have caused some exception that prevented the line return false from executing..

Comment: Yea, it was pretty easy to find once I opened up the console. Add this concept to your debugging toolbelt today!

Comment: I dont know how this answer was accepted even having errors in all funtions

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of errors in your code buddy | **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S52Wx/4/)**

```
function validacijaForme() {

var username = document.getElementById('usname');
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var pass1 = document.getElementById('pass1');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2');


 if(validacijaUsername(username) && validacijaEmail(email) && validacijaSifri(pass1,pass2))
{
  alert('success');
  return true;
}

return false;
}

function validacijaSifri(fieldId1, fieldId2)
{
var two = fieldId1.value;
var three = fieldId2.value;
if(two == three) { return true; }
alert("Warning!! passcodes must match!!!");
return false;
}

function validacijaUsername(usname)
{
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  

    if(letters.test(usname.value))  
    {  
      return true;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
      alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');  
      document.getElementById('usname').focus();  
      return false;  
    } 
}

function validacijaEmail(email)
{
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;  
if(mailformat.test(email.value))  
{  
  return true;  
}  
else  
{  
  alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");  
  document.getElementById('email').focus(); 
  return false;  
 }  

}
```

Comment: noted, I've been copying some code and that was obviously a bad idea, I've corrected it now, thanks..